# How to find most frequent pair in SQL?

Tags: mysql, data-manipulation

I am trying to write a query in MySQL that will output the most frequently occurring pair of values. I have the following table:

[Original Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVy6Q.png)

This table contains users' music streaming activity on a given day. I want to find out which pair of artists was the most frequently played one on a specific day. The answer should be (Pink Floyd, Queen) because 3 users listened to both artists on the same day. How can I achieve this?

I've started by joining the table onto itself using this code:

```
With temp as (
select person_id, artist_name, count(*) as times_played from users where date_played = '2020-10-01' group by 1,2)
select a.person_id, a.artist_name, b.artist_name from temp a join temp b
On a.person_id = b.person_id and a.artist_name != b. artist_name;
```

The result is the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xO4a.png):

I am not sure how to process from this point, so any help would be appreciated!

Below is the code to create the table in mySQL

```
create table users
(
  person_id       int,
  artist_name     varchar(255),
  date_played     date
);

insert into users
  (person_id, artist_name, date_played)
values
  (1, 'Pink Floyd', '2020-10-01'),
  (1, 'Led Zeppelin', '2020-10-01'),
  (1, 'Queen', '2020-10-01'),
  (1, 'Pink Floyd', '2020-10-01'),
  (2, 'Journey', '2020-10-01'),
  (2, 'Pink Floyd', '2020-10-01'),
  (2, 'Queen', '2020-10-01'),
  (2, 'Pink Floyd', '2020-10-01'),
  (3, 'Pink Floyd', '2020-10-01'),
  (3, 'Aerosmith', '2020-10-01'),
  (3, 'Queen', '2020-10-01'),
  (4, 'Pink Floyd', '2020-10-01'),
  (4, 'Led Zeppelin', '2020-10-01');
```

Comment: Relational tables need PRIMARY KEYs, so start with that

Comment: @Strawberry Your comments will always have the `KEY` to my heart.

Comment: @Strawberry, this is a fake table that I quickly put together to ask this question, but I see your point, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved my question thanks to the trick I found in the code provided by Tim Biegeleisen in this post (`u1.artist_name < u2.artist_name`):

```
With temp AS (
    SELECT 
        person_id, 
        artist_name 
    FROM users 
    WHERE date_played = '2020-10-01' 
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT
    u1.artist_name AS artist1,
    u2.artist_name AS artist2,
    COUNT(*) AS times_played,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Rnk
FROM temp u1
JOIN temp u2
ON u1.artist_name < u2.artist_name AND u1.person_id = u2.person_id
GROUP by 1,2
) sub

WHERE Rnk = 1;
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` will only return a single record.  What happens if two or more artist pairs happened to be tied for first place?

Comment: In that case, using the rank function you specified would solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can try handling this requirement using a self join along with the `RANK()` analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        u1.artist_name AS artist1,
        u2.artist_name AS artist2,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM users u1
    INNER JOIN users u2
        ON u1.artist_name < u2.artist_name AND u1.person_id = u2.person_id
    WHERE
        u1.date_played = u2.date_played
    GROUP BY
        u1.artist_name,
        u2.artist_name
)

SELECT
    artist1,
    artist2
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: could you please explain the logic of `u1.artist_name < u2.artist_name`

Comment: @PIG That criteria ensures that we only pair a first artist name which is lexicographically "less" than the second artist name.  That is, given the two names `Pink Floyd` and `Led Zeppelin`, it would only pair the former with the latter, but not vice-versa.  You may consider this as a means of avoiding double counting.

Comment: Thank you, @TimBiegeleisen, for offering a solution. Your trick about using `u1.artist_name < u2.artist_name` helped me come up with another solution, which I think is more intuitive and easy to understand.

Comment: @Anna_K Could you comment on whether or not my query works?  Also, feel free to post your own answer, if you have another way of doing this `:-)`

Comment: @Strawberry Don't keep me waiting in anticipation...do tell!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, your solution does work. My only problem with it is that you didn't join on member_id, so the original table increased in size multiple times and got quit messy. The only other minor issue (which you may not have been aware of) was that some users listened to the same artist on the same day more than once, so it was necessary to get rid of duplicate artists for each user, which I did using the group by statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen et voilà